# Detecting the Controller action being called while inside the beforeRoute callback

Tags: fat-free-framework

Playing with the Fat Free Framework, I am working on designing an Authorization Class to work with the built in Authentication Class. Based on my design I require the beforeRoute method to know the action that was called. Do I have access to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routing string or closure that was set to a route can be found in the `ROUTES` var:

```
var_dump($f3['ROUTES'][ $f3['PATTERN'] ][ $f3['AJAX']?2:3 ][ $f3['VERB'] ][0]);
```

(only works like this in v.3.3.1 and newer)

Comment: so you mean the dev branch on github? cuz I can not find a stable release 3.3.1.

Comment: ok, dropped the dev app and core files into my dir where 3.3.0 was and everything works fine. I do see how i can grab the string, but of course only when a string is used. For closures I can set whatever i need before the controller is called. Thanks!